# Setting a JComboBox editor using TableModelListener

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I wanted to set my 2nd column as `JComboBox` editor using `TableModelListener`. Also wanted to change the **Model** of ComboBox in 2nd column based on selected ComboBox in 1st column. Here I implemented a Listener that's listen to 1st column.

```
private class TableScheduleListener implements TableModelListener
{
    //Listening for data changes.
    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) 
    {
        int row = e.getFirstRow();
        int column = e.getColumn();
    }

    if(column == 1)
    {
            for(int i = 0; i < createScheduleView.tblSchedule.getRowCount(); i++)
            {
                createScheduleView.tblSchedule.getCellEditor(i, 2);
            }

            int col = createScheduleView.tblSchedule.convertColumnIndexToModel(2);

            if(col == 2 && createScheduleView.tblSchedule.getRowCount() < 7)
            {
                DefaultComboBoxModel cbModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(createScheduleModel.setData().toArray());
                createScheduleView.cbBreakStartTime.setModel(cbModel);
            }
     }
}
```

But I'm thinking how can I set as JComboBox as editor in my 2nd column. After settings it's model? Any help would appreciated.

UPDATE

I followed camickr tips from https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/28/combo-box-table-editor/
But wanted to override `TableCellEditor` from different class.

```
private class TableScheduleEditor extends JTable
{
    //  Determine editor to be used by row
    @Override
    public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
    {
        int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);

        if(modelColumn == 2 && row < 7)
        {
            DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(createScheduleModel.setData().toArray());
            createScheduleView.getCbBreakStartTime().setModel(model);
            return new DefaultCellEditor(createScheduleView.getCbBreakStartTime());
        }

        else
            return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
    };
}
```

I'm thinking how this class can register in my JTable?
I tried to register this in my constructor `this.createScheduleView.tblSchedule.setCellEditor(new TableScheduleEditor());`
But it says cannot be converted to TableCellEditor because it extends JTable. Any trick to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also wanted to change the Model of ComboBox in 2nd column based on selected ComboBox in 1st column

Override the `getCellEditor(...)` method of the `JTable` to return the appropriate editor.

Here is a basic example to get you started:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableComboBoxByRow extends JPanel
{
    List<String[]> editorData = new ArrayList<String[]>(3);

    public TableComboBoxByRow()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        // Create the editorData to be used for each row

        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Red", "Blue", "Green" } );
        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" } );
        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" } );

        //  Create the table with default data

        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Color", "Red"},
            {"Shape", "Square"},
            {"Fruit", "Banana"},
            {"Plain", "Text"}
        };
        String[] columnNames = {"Type","Value"};

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(model)
        {
            //  Determine editor to be used by row
            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
            {
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel( column );

                if (modelColumn == 1 && row < 3)
                {
                    JComboBox<String> comboBox1 = new JComboBox<String>( editorData.get(row));
                    return new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox1 );
                }
                else
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Combo Box by Row");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TableComboBoxByRow() );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the above example the "model" changes based on the row being edited.

In your case you will need to modify the logic to return the editor based on the value in the first column.

Comment: This actually works! Is it possible to override this in the different class by extending a `JTable`? But how can I register my table with this class? Please see my update above. Thanks!